# Is timestamp an utc time? How to get utc time in java and convert to local time (millis)?

Tags: java, time, timestamp, utc

Is TIMESTAMP an utc time? 
How to get utc time in java and convert to local time (millis)?

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? What research have you done?

Comment: I found System.currentTimeMillis() is a local time, but the code I found to get utc time is a little ... long(Well I mean ... not one line code), so I just wonder whether a local time or an utc time should I use for timestamp ... better?

Comment: Which timestamp? A database `TIMESTAMP`, a `java.sql.Timestamp`, something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a timestamp object to local time:

```
object.toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toLocalDateTime--

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

Use SimpleDateFormatter to convert it into local time (millis.)

Answer (score 0):

Well I just found a way to get UTC time, it works but I don't know whether it is a good way.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int zoneOffset = cal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);
int dstOffset = cal.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);
cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -(zoneOffset + dstOffset));
```